# Invalid Operants 'float' and 'Vector2' in operator '+'

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I am trying to make left and right movements for mobile, I have made 2 `TouchScreenButton`s and a `CanvasLayer` for them. Here is my script:

```
extends Sprite2D

const speed : int = 5

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.


# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("game_left"):
        position.x += Vector2.LEFT * speed * delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("game_right"):
        position.x += Vector2.RIGHT * speed * delta
```

I was trying to make a right and left movement for a 2d mobile game, but I got the Invalid Operants 'float' and 'Vector2' in operator '+' error.

Comment: `Vector2.RIGHT` is still a `Vector2`, but `position.x` is a `float`. Try adding directly to `position`, if it is also a `Vactor2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
position.x += Vector2.LEFT * speed * delta
```

Here `position` is a vector and you take its X component which is a float. Then you use `Vector2.LEFT` to add to it but that is a vector, not a float. As the error says you can’t add vectors to scalars.

Most likely left is a negative value and right positive, so remove `Vector2.LEFT` and subtract the other parts, and remove `Vector2.RIGHT` and keep the addition:

```
position.x -= speed * delta
```